# R Shell and Kerberos Ticket

Tags: r, kerberos

I have a hive connection via JDBC in RStudio without problems, I create Kerberos ticket in `Tools < Shell: kinit` and all working fine, I can use Kerberos TGT.

But if I make the same method via shell/ssh and loading R in terminal (Not RStudio), R can't use Kerberos TGT File and fails.

How can i use the Kerberos ticket?

```
> [user@server ~]$: kinit
>
> Password for user@domain:  --i put the password--
>
> [user@server ~]$: R 
>
> -- R load --
>
> \> source('samecode.r')
>
> Error Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not create secure connection to jdbc:hive2:....etc
```

Any idea? This error happens in RStudio if we not create the ticket, but when it's created in tools>shell all work fine, in console its impossible.
I try to create it with

```
 system('kinit');
```

And create the ticket fine, but can't use it in the rest of the code.

Comment: For the record, your sentence *"i have a hdfs connection via JDBC"* does not make sense; HDFS is a file system, Hive is a database (kind of).

Comment: thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi you can create a kerberos ticket within R with a `keytab` file and this command :

```
system("kinit username@ADS.IU.EDU -k -t username.keytab")
```

To create the `keytab` you have to do this via shell :

```
ktutil
ktutil:  addent -password -p username@ADS.IU.EDU -k 1 -e rc4-hmac
Password for username@ADS.IU.EDU: [enter your password]
ktutil:  addent -password -p username@ADS.IU.EDU -k 1 -e aes256-cts
Password for username@ADS.IU.EDU: [enter your password]
ktutil:  wkt username.keytab
ktutil:  quit
```

All the steps for creating a `keytab` are explained [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aumh)

And the `keytab` file must be in your working directory.

Comment: Actually the `keytab` can be in any directory. And the encryption types depend on the actual Kerberos config at KDC level, e.g. our cluster requires `aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96` -- check with your SysAdmin

Comment: The working directory is an R thing, if you don't specify the path to the `keytab` the `system` command expect that the file is in the directory register in your R session. And thanks for the encryption details, I didn't know about that.

Comment: This answer just saved me so much headache from having to initialize ssh keys and setting up putty to run a Spark context through Microsoft R Client. Thank you!